# Java: error cannot find symbol - why is this an error and not an exception?

Tags: java, exception

I'm relatively new to Java, and trying to understand the rationale behind making this an error, rather than an exception.

I've read in several places that an error:

> "indicates serious problems that a reasonable application should not try to catch"

In my case, I've made a method called getAttribute, containing a switch to return various field values depending on the attribute requested.  In this instance it seemed more elegant than to have getter methods for each of these attributes.  Here's a sample of the code:

```
public class JPXmlWord implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @XmlAttribute(name = "Kanji")
        private String kanji;
        @XmlAttribute(name = "Kana")
        private String kana;
        @XmlAttribute(name = "English")
        private String english;
        @XmlAttribute(name = "Romaji")
        private String romaji;
        @XmlAttribute(name = "Katakana")
        private String katakana;
        public String getAttribute( String attribute ) throws Exception {
            switch ( attribute ) {
                case ("kanji"):
                    return this.kanji;
                case ("kana"):
                    return this.kana;
                case ("english"):
                    return this.english;
                case ("romaji"):
                    return this.romaji;
                case ("katakana"):
                    return this.katakana;
                default:
                    throw new Exception();
            } 
        }
```

By request, so you can reproduce the missing symbol error (same error you'd get requesting any missing symbol from any class):

```
JPXmlWord word = new JPXmlWord();
word.getAttribute("nonExistentAttribute");
```

Wanting to throw an exception specific to when an inexistent field is requested, I tried requesting an inexistent field in jshell to see what specific exception gets thrown, but got an error rather than exception.

Why is the request for an inexistent field considered a problem "that a reasonable application should not try to catch"?

I'm worried there is something I don't grasp about Java philosophy, because I am surprised by this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211116/discussion-on-question-by-malcolm-wright-java-error-cannot-find-symbol-why-is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly your code is something like this

```java
public class Main {
    private String field1;
    private String field2;

    public String getAttribute(String name) {
        switch (name) {
            case "field1":
                return this.field1;
            case "field2":
                return this.field2;
            case "notDeclaredField":
                return this.notDeclaredField; // <- this is simply an error that the javac is telling you about
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid name");
        }
    }
}
```

and the problem you are facing is that your code can't be compiled because you reference a field that is not declared. This is because Java is a language that enforces that field, type, methods, etc. need to be defined (at compile time) before they are used.
You seam to come from lanugages like python where you *define* an instance field by using it.

```py
class Class:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def setAtt(self, value):
        self.field = value # this is okay in python
```

On the otherhand the below code would perfectly compile and do what you seam to expect

```java
public class Main {
    private String field1;
    private String field2;

    public String getAttribute(String name) {
        switch (name) {
            case "field1":
                return this.field1;
            case "field2":
                return this.field2;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid name");
        }
    }
}
```

notice that there is no access to a field that is not declared.
But if you have a fixed set of attributes you want to be able to access you should simply write a getter for each one. This way you get the safty that the field/attribute is present at compile time rather than at runtime.

But if you want to be able to add attributes to your class instance at runtime, you should use a `Map<,>` to keep track of theri values

```java
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Main {
    private HashMap<String, String> atts = new HashMap<>();

    public String getAttribute(String name) {
        if (atts.containsKey(name)) {
            return atts.get(name);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("There is not attribute with the name: " + name);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {}
}
```